# Show that $H = \{a \in G \ | \ ax=xa \ \forall x \in G\}$ is an abelian subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> **Problem Statement:** Let $G$ be a group. Show that $H = \{a \in G \ | \ ax=xa \ \forall x \in G\}$ is an abelian subgroup of G.

It is easy to show that H is a subgroup, but I couldn't show that it is also abelian. My attempt is by taking two arbitrary $m, n \in H$ so $mx=xm$ and $nx=xn$ for all $x$ in G. Thus, $m=xmx^{-1}$ and $n=xnx^{-1}$. So, $mn = (xmx^{-1})(xnx^{-1}) = xmnx^{-1}$.

How can I continue this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $m,n \in H$. Then $n \in G$ ($H \le G \implies H \subseteq G$). Since

$$mg=gm$$

for any $g \in G$, it holds in particular when $g := n$, i.e.

$$mn=nm$$

---

*Addendum:* This set $H$ has a special name: it is called the **center** of $G$ and is often denoted $Z(G)$. You may find more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)).

Comment: It was a duplicate.